# Is there any way to shorten these lines?

Tags: javascript

I have an emoji input app, which has array like features. I want it so if you type the emoji's name instead of actually pasting it it appears.

I've tried searching online for ways to make this code better but they are all specific.

```js
addToBeginning.addEventListener("click", () => {

      let o = inputEl.value

      if (o.toLowerCase() === "honeypot") {
        emojis.unshift("")
        const q = emojis.join(" ")
        emojiOutput.textContent = q
        inputEl.value = "";
        inputEl.focus()
      } else if (o.toLowerCase() == "chocolate") {
        emojis.unshift("")
        const q = emojis.join(" ")
        emojiOutput.textContent = q
        inputEl.value = "";
        inputEl.focus()
      } // etc , have like 10 more lines that follow this same format, all hardcoded
```

Comment: Seems like a mapping of the string name to the emoji would suffice.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML and more JS to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look them up:

```js
const emojis = []
const allEmojis = {
  "honeypot": "",
  "chocolate": ""
}

addToBeginning.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let o = inputEl.value.toLowerCase();
  const emoji = allEmojis[o];
  if (!emoji) return; // or give error and return
  emojis.unshift(emoji)
  const q = emojis.join(" ")
  emojiOutput.textContent = q;
  inputEl.value = "";
  inputEl.focus()
})
```

Comment: Just add check if that emoji actually exists in map

Answer (score 3):

You can just create an object that maps the name to an emoji. The rest is almost the same

```
let o = inputEl.value.toLowerCase();

const emojiMap = {
  honeypot: '',
  chocolate: '',
  pizza: '',
  burger: '',
};

const emoji = emojiMap[o.toLowerCase()];

if(emoji) {
  emojis.unshift(emoji);

  const q = emojis.join(" ");
  emojiOutput.textContent = q;

  inputEl.value = "";
  inputEl.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lookup map and only append an emoji if it is found.

```js
const
  inputEl = document.querySelector('.message'),
  emojiOutput = document.querySelector('.output'),
  addToBeginning = document.querySelector('.add');

const emojiLookupMap = {
  'honeypot'  : '',
  'chocolate' : ''
};

const emojiList = [];

const update = (emoji) => {
  emojiList.unshift(emoji);
  emojiOutput.textContent = emojiList.join(' ')
  inputEl.value = '';
}

const parseEmoji = (e) => {
  const
    value = inputEl.value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    emoji = emojiLookupMap[value]
  if (emoji) update(emoji);
  inputEl.focus();
};

addToBeginning.addEventListener('click', parseEmoji);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="message" />
<button class="add">Parse Emoji</button>
<p class="output"></p>
```